# She had her report done. (who did the report?)

Tags: sentence-meaning, causative-have

> She had her report done.

She did the report or someone else did the report?

'have' is a causative verb and here took the past participle as an object complement.

I wonder who really did the report because there are two cases where something is done by myself or by other people excluding me.

Comment: This would benefit from more context - can you give us a longer quote, please?

Comment: @Stephie excerp from a dictionary without more context

Comment: What is the purpose of this excerpt? What word or phrase is being defined?

Comment: the verb 'have' and takes a form of past participle as its complement if the object is a thing: not a person

Comment: These context free extracts are a bit pointless. You are asking "what does this thing that means something in context mean if you remove the context"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks, without context, for meaning that can only be supplied by context.

Comment: On its own the phrase is ambiguous. "She had her report done by the doctor" (the doctor wrote it) or "She had her report done by Friday" (she wrote it) it could be either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible to say.

This might be an example of a causative, implying that she caused someone else to do the report:

> She had her report done for her by her sister, but the teacher spotted the change in handwriting and both girls got into trouble.

But it could equally be a usage like:

> She worked through the evening so she had her report done on time.

Here it means "she caused the completion by working hard" and doesn't mean that someone else did the work.